# When does a representation of $H\subset G$ on $V$ extend to a representation of $G$ on $V$?

Tags: group-theory, representation-theory, group-cohomology

Let $G$ be a finite group, $H$ a subgroup, and $\varphi:H\rightarrow GL(V)$ a finite-dimensional representation of $H$ over a characteristic zero, algebraically closed field. Let $\chi$ be the character of this representation.

If $\chi$ takes different values on two different conjugacy classes in $H$ that become conjugate in $G$, then clearly $\varphi$ cannot extend to a representation of $G$ on $V$.

**Is this the only obstruction?**

I.e. if $\chi$ is the restriction of a class function on $G$, is $\varphi$ the restriction of a representation of $G$ on $V$?

Another way to ask the question is, with this assumption about $\chi$, does there exist a class function that extends $\chi$ and is equal to an $\mathbb{N}$-linear combination of irreducible characters of $G$?

Or are there other things that can go wrong? And if there are, are they straightforward to test for, or is there some whole subtle cohomological theory of obstructions, or what?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is an example where it cannot extend. Let $H$ be a subgroup of order $2$ that lies in the commutator subgroup of $G$ (for example a subgroup of order $2$ in $A_4$) and let $\phi$ be the nontrivial linear representation of $H$ that maps the element of order $2$ to $-I$. Then, since $H \le [G,G]$, $H$ lies in the kernel of any linear representation of $G$, so $\phi$ cannot extend to a representation of $G$.

In geenral you cannot expect representations to extend in this way.

Comment: Do you know if there is any literature on how to identify the special case where a representation of $H$ extends to $G$?

Comment: There are some results about the case when $H$ is a normal subgroup of $G$. See for example http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/0021869385902030

Comment: I imagine you want your representation of $H$ to be one-dimensional, so that being in $[G,G]$ means being in the kernel of the rep?

Comment: Yes that's right.

Comment: @DerekHolt - thanks, just the kind of thing I was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

The example you gave about $H$ having two conjugacy classes which become conjugate in $G$ is wrong. We can actually still find a value of $\chi\uparrow G$. (This is read "$\chi$ induced to $G$").

Let's say $x_1^H$ and $x_2^H$ are two conjugacy classes in $H$ which become a single conjugacy class $x^G$ in $G$. Then the formula for $g\in x^G$ is

$$\chi(g)=|C_G(g)|\left(\frac{\chi(x_1)}{|C_H(x_1)|}+\frac{\chi(x_2)}{|C_H(x_2)|}\right)$$

Comment: I am asking for a representation of $G$ *on the same space*. The induced representation is a representation of $G$ on a bigger space that contains $V$.