# Extending a character of an abelian group to an overgroup

Tags: group-theory, representation-theory

This question follows up [this one](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1387903/when-does-a-representation-of-h-subset-g-on-v-extend-to-a-representation-of), restricting the scope.

**Setting:** Let $A$ be an abelian group and let $\chi:A\rightarrow\mathbb{C}^\times$ be a character of $A$, and let $G$ be a group containing $A$ as a subgroup and such that every proper subgroup of $G$ is abelian.

My question is what conditions on $A$ and $\chi$ can guarantee that $\chi$ can extend to a one-dimensional representation $\varphi: G\rightarrow \mathbb{C}^\times = GL(1,\mathbb{C})$ of $G$.

More specifically:

If $\chi$ is nontrivial on $A\cap [G,G]$, then no $\varphi$ exists, since $\varphi$ (if it exists) is necessarily trivial on commutators.

This subsumes the condition mentioned in the linked question, that if $\chi$ takes different values on two distinct elements of $A$ that become conjugate in $G$ then $\varphi$ can't exist, because in this latter case, $\chi(gag^{-1})\neq\chi(a)$ and therefore $[g,a]\neq 1$.

So, my question:

**Question:**

> Is this the only obstruction?
>
> In other words, in the setting described, if $\chi$ is trivial on the part of $[G,G]$ contained in $A$, do we know that $\varphi: G\rightarrow\mathbb{C}^\times$ with $\varphi\mid_\chi$ exists?

**A thought that prompted the question:** The condition is certainly met if $G$ is abelian, because then there are no nontrivial commutators; and in this case, $\varphi$ certainly exists.

Comment: If $\chi$ is trivial on $A \cap [G,G]$ then it extends to $G$. But not all elements of $[G,G]$ are necessarily commutators, so it is possible for $\chi$ to be trivial on all commutators of $G$ contained in $A$ but nontrivial on $A \cap [G,G]$, in which case it would not extend.

Comment: @DerekHolt - Okay, I'll fix the question to reflect that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Derek Holt says in the comments, the answer is **yes**.

In fact, this does not depend on the assumption that $G$'s proper subgroups are abelian or even the assumption that $A$ is abelian:

Let $A\subset G$ be groups, and let $\chi:A\rightarrow\mathbb{C}^\times$ be a one-dimensional representation of $A$ that is trivial on $A\cap [G,G]$. Then $\chi$ factors through $A$'s image in $G$'s abelianization. Let $\tilde A$ be this image and $\tilde \chi:\tilde A\rightarrow \mathbb{C}^\times$ the character of $\tilde A$ given by this factorization. Then $\tilde\chi$ extends to a character $\tilde\varphi : G/[G,G]\rightarrow\mathbb{C}^\times$, since characters of abelian groups always extend. Precomposing with the canonical $G\rightarrow G/[G,G]$, we obtain a one-dimensional representation $\varphi$ of $G$ extending $\chi$.